# How do I make the Android Flutter app icon smaller?

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

I build Android Flutter app and it works well but there is one problem when I open the app drawer.

The app's logo looks like this. And I have small and big size version.

The logo looks like this.

[image]

I use it like this

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

but when I build the app the logo looks to big so I have to fix it. I searched related keywords but there are only answer that icon makes bigger.

[image]

How can I make it icon smaller? I already tried smaller image but results are same.

Comment: Hi there. What are your current logo dimensions ?

Comment: @NisanthReddy I tried 531x531 and 30x30 px size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the step

1. Open **android** folder in Android Studio
2. Wait until project initialise or indexing
3. After indexing complete, Right click on **app** folder from side-menu
4. New > Image Asset
5. New pop-up will open, In **Source Asset** section you can select your logo and set a logo size with help of below slider in **Scaling** section

Comment: In the newer versions of Android Studio and Flutter, Image Asset is no longer there! Where can it be found?

Comment: @ClWin I am using Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1 and the Image Asset option is still there. Kindly make sure you have opened only the **android** folder in Android Studio and not the entire flutter project.